# Access to command line user arguments using getopt

Tags: c++, getopt

I am writing a program that processes options from the user and functions as programmed using getopt. My question is, how do I display an error if the user enters an invalid option? Also, I want to access the variable in order to display it in the error message. Here is a snapshot of my code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    enum {
        WHOLE, PREFIX, ANYWHERE, SUFFIX, EMBEDDED
    } mode;
    bool reverse_match = false;
    bool ignore_case = false;
    bool specify_length = false;

    int c;
    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "wpsavein:")) != -1) {
        switch (c) {
        case '?':
            std::cerr << "Unrecognised option " << std::endl;
            std::cerr << "Usage: match [-OPTION]... PATTERN [FILENAME]..." << std::endl;
            return 2;
            break;
        case 'w': // pattern matches whole word
            mode = WHOLE;
            break;
        case 'p': // pattern matches prefix
            mode = PREFIX;
            //cout << "test: " << optarg << endl;
            break;
        case 'a': // pattern matches anywhere
            mode = ANYWHERE;
            break;
        case 's': // pattern matches suffix
            mode = SUFFIX;
            break;
        case 'v': // reverse sense of match
            reverse_match = true;
            break;
        case 'e': // pattern matches anywhere
            mode = EMBEDDED;
            break;
        case 'i': // ignore case
            ignore_case = true;
            break;
        case 'n': // specifies length of match
            specify_length = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I used the `cerr` stream to display the error, but I would like it to also include user input. For instance if the user input `-t`, the error would be:

```
Unrecognised option -t
Usage: match [-OPTION]... PATTERN [FILENAME]...
```

What I am getting is:

```
invalid option -- 't'
Unrecognised option -t
Usage: match [-OPTION]... PATTERN [FILENAME]...
```

I believe the `invalid option -- 't'` is the default, but is there a way I can modify or not include it? and also get access to user-specified option?

Comment: Have you tried reading `getopt`'s manual page. It answers all of these questions.

Comment: You can read `optopt` and set `opterr` to achieve this. [See the manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragment of manual from getopt:

> If getopt() does not recognize an option character, it prints an
>          error message to stderr, stores the character in optopt, and returns
>          '?'.  The calling program may prevent the error message by setting
>          opterr to 0.

What you need to do:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  opterr = 0;
  int c;
  while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "wpsavein:")) != -1) {
    switch (c) {
      case '?':
        std::cerr << "Unrecognised option -" << static_cast<char>(optopt)
                  << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Usage: match [-OPTION]... PATTERN [FILENAME]..."
                  << std::endl;
        return 2;
        break;
    }
  }
}
```